# Disregarding NA value with summary statistics

Tags: r, summary

I am trying to run summary statistics using the `summary()` function with a large dataset which contains missing values.

When I run the `summary()` function, mean, median and other summary statistics come up as NA for some variables.

Is there a way to disregard NA values when getting summary/descriptive statistics?

(I do not want to delete the observations, just disregard them when running that function.)

Comment: ``summary(x, na.omit=T)``

Answer (score 0):

I made a replicable example that will help you. A good alternative to your problem: "calculate descriptive statistics for all variables in a dataset that have NA values" can be the "dplyr" package.

```
# df to replicable example 
mtcars <- mtcars

# count NA values
mtcars %>% summarise_all(~ sum(is.na(.)))

# another way to do the same thing 
sapply(mtcars, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))


# input some NA's
mtcars$hp[mtcars$hp >= 110] <- NA
mtcars$qsec[mtcars$qsec >= 19] <- NA

# count NA values
mtcars %>% summarise_all(~ sum(is.na(.)))


# summary statistics 
mtcars %>%
  summarise_all(funs(sum, mean),na.rm=TRUE)

# consider some groups to 
unique(mtcars$carb)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(carb) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(sum, mean),na.rm=TRUE)
```

another simpler option

```
install.packages("pastecs")
library(pastecs)
stat.desc(mtcars,  basic=TRUE, desc=TRUE, norm=TRUE, p=0.95)
```

Answer (score -3):

You can store your dataset in a new variable using `na.omit` and then call `summary()` on the new variable:

```
summary(data_NAomit <- na.omit(data))
```

What does *not* work is

```
summary(x, na.omit = T)
```

because `na.omit` is not an argument for `summary()`.

Comment: I tried these commands here and I was not successful. Could you edit your answer to include an example?

Comment: I think I misunderstood OP's question and I could not replicate his problem now that I think I understood it.   
They said that the mean and median are NA when using summary(), but that is not the case when I do it. Using your mtcars variant, summary() will count the NAs for hp and qsec and show them in the result, but the mean and median are still calculated normally.  
I thought he wanted to remove the NAs entirely, but now I'm not sure what the problem is in the first place. I apologize for the confusion.